# Get response object API in grails

Tags: grails

This is the method:

```
def index() {
    RestBuilder rest = new RestBuilder()
    def resp = rest.get("http://192.168.1.212:9000/api/books") {
        accept("application/json")
        contentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        return resp as JSON
    }
}
```

When I render `resp` just `object grails.plugins.rest.client.RestBuilder@4b1c57c4` is displayed in the browser.

can you help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to StakOverflow @Arun | Please add sufficient details about what is happening and what you want to do...

Comment: i just want to get object or data from given url and return as json format

Comment: what error are you getting ... ?

Comment: when render resp just object grails.plugins.rest.client.RestBuilder@4b1c57c4 display in browser

Answer (score 1):

You have placed your `return` in the wrong spot. The way you have it written is only returning from the closure, not your controller method. You just have to move your `return` to outside of the closure. You also can just use the `RestResponse.json` field to get the JSON.

```
def index() {
    RestBuilder rest = new RestBuilder()
    return rest.get("http://192.168.1.212:9000/api/books") {
        accept("application/json")
        contentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    }.json
}
```

Just be aware that this does not handle any potential errors, such as not receiving a proper response from your endpoint, or not being able to connect to the endpoint at all. You would just need to expand on this with error handling when the need arises.

Answer (score -1):

You place the return into the closure and this is wrong
Try with this

```
def index() {
    RestBuilder rest = new RestBuilder()
     rest.get("http://192.168.1.212:9000/api/books") {
           accept("application/json")
           contentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        }
 }
```

Comment: [{"id":1,"title":"The First Man","price":535.0,"author":{"id":1}},{"id":2,"title":"Truth And Dare: Velocity","price":725.0,"author":{"id":1}}] this is json data given url . and I just  want mapping custom groovy class as Books

Comment: so your question was "get response object" an this is the way. We can't know if you have more requirements if you don't write from the beginner

Comment: This just returns exactly the same thing as Arun's original code. It will return the object's qualified name and internal object ID instead of the JSON expected.

Comment: input json:[{"price":"2300","author":"Arun","name":"Java","id":1},{"price":"2500","author":"Theeng","name":"C++","id":2}] then want to this string format : def myJson = "[{\"id\":1, \"price\":37,\"name\":\"Java\",\"author\":\"arun\"}, " +
                    "{\"id\":2, \"price\":300,\"name\":\"C++\",\"author\":\"theeng\"}]"